# How to make stat_binhex shown on a log scale in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, hexagonal-tiles

I have a 2d hexagon density plot with many points. I would like the counts within the hexagons to be displayed on a logarithmic scale, but I can't figure out how to do this through ggplot2.

Here is a simple example:

```
x <- runif(1000, 50, 100) 
y <- rnorm(1000, mean = 10, sd = 8)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x, y))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + stat_binhex()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a `fill` aesthetics that defaults to `..count..` when you do not specify it in `stat_binhex`. The code below produces same plot as your original code.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + stat_binhex(aes(fill=..count..))
```

[image]

If you want to have a log scale for counts, then the solution is pretty straight forward:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + stat_binhex(aes(fill=log(..count..)))
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't work for me in ggplot2_2.1.0: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'count' not found

Comment: @daknowles this is most likely caused by a bug in ggplot2: [#1608](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1608)

Comment: As of ggplot 3.4.0 one should use `after_stat(count)` instead of `..count..` as the latter is deprecated

Answer (score 12):

Another way is to pass `trans =` argument to `scale_fill_*` used.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_hex() + scale_fill_gradient(trans = "log")
ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_hex() + scale_fill_viridis_c(trans = "log")
```

[image]

Comment: The automatic tickmark selection and numbering is a lot less nice in this solution, but otherwise I like it.

Comment: trans="log10" or trans="log2" gives nicer tickmarks